# c++17 how to write is_pointer_pointer generic lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, generic-programming

```
auto is_pointer_pointer = [] ( auto arg ) -> bool {
     // implementation here
}
```

How would one approach implementing this generic lambda?

usage example:

```
int main ( int argc, char ** argv ) {
     auto dp = is_pointer_pointer(argv) ; // returns true
}
```

**Solution**

Thanks to @luk32. His solution (aka "Answer") I have taken to the wandbox, and made it a bit more resilient. Code is [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YQyba6VWt7lXhpVN).

The solution is this lambda:

```
  // return true if argument given is
  // pointer to pointer of it's type T
  // T ** arg
  auto is_pointer_pointer = [&] ( const auto & arg ) constexpr -> bool {
    using arg_type = std::decay_t< decltype(arg) > ;
     return std::is_pointer_v<arg_type> && 
       std::is_pointer_v< std::remove_pointer_t<arg_type> > ;
 };
```

For the thirsty of knowledge [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0428r2.pdf) is the article explaining the c++17 generic lambda issue with auto args. Hint: that is why I use std::decay above.

Comment: You mean to return true if arg is of type `double*`? Or some kind of `T**`?

Comment: You could put your solution in an answer instead, perhaps that would be a bit clearer. It's a normal practice to answer your own question if you have an original solution.

Comment: I have no original solution, I adopted @luk32 solution and made it a bit more resilient. Have you up voted his solution aka "Answer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already possible in c++14 using `decltype` and `type_traits` facilities.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
  auto is_double_pointer = [] ( auto arg ) -> bool {
    return std::is_same<decltype(arg), double*>::value;
  };

  auto is_pointer_pointer = [] ( auto arg ) -> bool {
    return std::is_pointer<decltype(arg)>::value && 
           std::is_pointer< typename std::remove_pointer<decltype(arg)>::type >::value;
  };


  double d, *ptrd, **ptrptrd;

  std::cout << is_double_pointer(d) << '\n';
  std::cout << is_double_pointer(ptrd) << '\n';
  std::cout << is_double_pointer(ptrptrd) << '\n';
  std::cout << is_pointer_pointer(d) << '\n';
  std::cout << is_pointer_pointer(ptrd) << '\n';
  std::cout << is_pointer_pointer(ptrptrd) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
0
0
0
1
```

EDIT: Also works for `char** argv;`

Comment: thanks.  By "double" in this context I mean "pointer to pointer" aka "double pointer" not a pointer to type double .. but your solution might work for any type. perhaps. perhaps https://wandbox.org might prove you right, if you paste your code ove there and make it work for T? Thanks once more.

Comment: There are two versions, for both interpretations and they work for what they are supposed to do. It can't be more self explanatory IMO. Take the code, play with it, see it works.

Comment: Ok thanks @luk32, I have played and it works and I made it resilient.